# Scala templates in Playframework2

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-1.x

Have have tried earlier with `Play1.2.3` ..I so loved the framework.

Now am trying to start a web application for this I wanted to give a try with `Play2.0.2` (Latest).

Downloaded Play2.0.2 Java version ..

```
*Play new myFirstApp >>  play run >> Done as expected.* (Selected a simple Java app option 2  )
```

Had a closer look at the `html` files inside `views`

`index.scala` & `main.scala` Why ?

Later have opened the `index.scala` html file 
Have found this :

```
 @(message: String)

 @main("Welcome to Play 2.0") {

   @play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")

 }
```

Unable to understand the above template code?

Do I need to have `scala` knowledge to get along with future `Playframework` versions?

Comment: I know Scala pretty well, but without reading the documentation, I wasn't able to understand the templates either. I suggest you do that.

Comment: @KimStebel : Have gone through the document, The
Scala statements starts with the special `@` character.Does this mean all my views will be rendered into scala templates? Unable to understand a lot of scala things in `play2.0`..so my question comes,do I need to learn `scala` to use `Play2.0.2`

Comment: The templates are translated into Scala code, but in a well written application, you won't have much logic in the templates anyway.

Comment: @KimStebel : True As amnt going to put any logic in the UI ...but just want to be sure before kick off with latest play version  about scala things.. If there is pretty much scala involved in it,I better stick to earlier version which was well documented and managed.

Comment: I use the scala version, but as far as I know, there is a Java API for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a little Scala knowledge, but in range required in templates that, what you can find in the docs will be enough.

`index.scala.html` is a template only for this one page, `main.scala.html` is a layout it's similar to

[Template decorators : #{extends /} and #{doLayout /}](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates) from 1.2.x (scroll to that section)

Beside this you can create your controllers and models in pure Java, see samples included to the Play 2 sources, you will get it in short time, can ensure you.

Comment: +1 for clarifying.. One more qn : Do I need to re-write entire application which was written in `play 1.2.3` ?

Comment: Yes, you will not be able to make easy import, as Play 1 and 2 differs a lot.

Comment: Ohhh..gives me an impression to think one step further.. Is it going to be the same for future `x` versions?

Comment: I don't think so, Play 2.0 has changed massively as in version 1 core team realized what do they want from custom framework. I think that they will use this knowledge in the future, therefore there is big chance, that Play 2 will be supported longer and further than 1. That's my opinion